# Simple Django Form

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement a Twitter-like follow system (one user can follow and be followed by many other users). I've tried a number of ways, but I keep getting errors. Currently, every time I drop debuggers or print statements throughout the form, I find that I don't ever get into the clean methods, nor is kwargs ever populated with values.

I want to be able to pass in the `follower` & `following` as arguments to the Form and just assign them in the `__init__` but everything is going wrong. When I get the response back in Javascript (React & Redux), all I'm getting is errors for both `follower` & `following` saying "This field is required."

Here's what I've got so far:

**Models**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'

class UserFollow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey('User', models.CASCADE, related_name='follows')
    following = models.ForeignKey('User', models.CASCADE, related_name='followed_by')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('follower', 'following')

    def to_user(self):
        return {
            'id': self.pk,
            'follower': self.follower.pk,
            'following': self.following.pk
        }
```

**Views**

```
def follow(request, id):
    following = User.objects.get(pk=id)
    form = UserFollowForm(follower=request.user, following=following)
    if form.is_valid():
        user_follow = form.save()
        return JsonResponse({'user_followed': following.to_user()})
    return JsonResponse({'error': form.errors}, status=400)
```

**Forms**

```
class UserFollowForm(forms.ModelForm):
    follower = forms.CharField()
    following = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserFollow
        fields = ('follower', 'following')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.follower = kwargs.pop('follower', None)
        self.following = kwargs.pop('following', None)
        super(UserFollowForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_follower(self):
        return self.follower

    def clean_following(self):
        return self.following
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't passed any data into the form, so it is not bound and will never be validated.

However I don't understand why you want to use a form here at all. You don't seem to want to take posted data from the user, and there is no validation to be done. Just create your UserFollow instance directly.

```
def follow(request, id):
    following = User.objects.get(pk=id)
    user_follow = UserFollow.objects.create(follower=request.user, following=following)
    return JsonResponse({'user_followed': user_follow.to_user()})
```

Comment: By data, you mean an argument like `data={....}`? And as to your second point, that's an interesting idea. I've sort of gotten used to the idea of just using forms for everything, not remembering what they're specifically intended for.

Comment: As stated in the answer, the way you handle it, it's useless to pass by a form. But yeah, to initiate a form, you have to do ```form = UserFollowForm(data=request.POST)```. Fields will be filled from the keys name, and other will be sent in kwargs